# how to add multiple roles to an admin user in Apache tomcat 8?

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat8, user-roles

Recently i've installed an apache tomcat 8.
my tomcat-users.xml contains this:

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <user username="tomcat" password="pass1234" roles="admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

I want to enable openning manager app and server status on this user too.
can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding multiple roles might be achieved by the following in tomcat-users XML file

```
<user username="craigmcc" password="secret" roles="standard,manager-script" />
```

The manager GUI is given access via the role "manager-gui". The server status is given via role "manager-script".

But the manager-script role is not provided with CSRF. Hence, it is not advisable to have one user with both GUI and SCRIPT roles.

In your Tomcat- check the error pages for 403. It has most of the details that i provided above.

NOTE: This is in reference to Tomcat 7.